# Python: sys.stdout.flush() vs. sys.stdout.buffer.flush()?

Tags: python, buffer, stdout, flush

Let's say you need to write binary data to standard output:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(data)
```

Then to flush it you can use either of these two:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
```

Both of these two calls seem to work the same way in a simple situation. *However*:

- the first one calls flush on the whole `stdout` object (`_io.TextIOWrapper`)
- the second one calls flush only on the `buffer` sub-object (`_io.BufferedWriter`).

What are the situations where one would prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally the difference between the `TextIOWrapper` and `BufferedWriter` is what they are designed to process. Having a look at the Python documentation you'll see that `BufferedWriter` is designed to handle byte streams:

> [BufferedIOBase](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) deals with buffering on a raw byte stream ([RawIOBase](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase)). Its subclasses, [BufferedWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedWriter), [BufferedReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader), and [BufferedRWPair](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedRWPair) buffer streams that are readable, writable, and both readable and writable.

While the `TextIOWrapper` is designed to handle byte-streams that are specific to text, handling things like encoding and decoding.

> Another [IOBase](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase) subclass, [TextIOBase](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase), deals with streams whose bytes represent text, and handles encoding and decoding from and to [unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) strings. [TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper), which extends it, is a buffered text interface to a buffered raw stream ([BufferedIOBase](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase)).

As for which one you should be calling flush on. It's a wash since the `TextIOWrapper` is actually just a nice wrapper for text `BufferedIOBase`. So if, as you say, you are actually handling binary data and not text-based data, then you could just use the `BufferedIOBase`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use `BufferedIOBase` in place of `sys.stdout.buffer` for a more complete answer? (I.e. does one have to create a new object, what are the arguments, etc.)

Comment: I think I have answered the question you asked reasonably. If you wanted to know how to use the `BufferedIOBase` class you could always look at [resources like these](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/26237/io.BufferedIOBase)